# ValueError: unknown format is not supported : ROC Curve

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have just updated python version from 3.5 to 3.7 and getting an error in constructing ROC curve. I did not change anything in code but it gives some unknown error

**Code**

```
# ROC Curve

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, roc_auc_score, roc_curve
y_pred_proba = predictions[::, 1]
print("y_pred_proba", y_pred_proba)
print("y_test", y_test)

fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_proba)
auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
```

**Values**

**y_pred_proba** [0.1746994  0.22792926 0.60020134 0.60857445 0.38630289 0.16318228
0.20503542 0.76781874 0.89951127 0.13657112 0.36836385 0.23833946
0.43924601 0.9874083  0.98404103 0.1003149  0.94596688 0.36480605
0.48716601 0.04158647 0.8624937  0.93881636 0.54065999 0.38538261
0.48002784 0.9874083  0.76781874 0.95791353 0.48002784 0.2448756
0.98404103 0.06473023 0.34080482 0.11897602 0.07883822 0.08000581
0.38630289 0.2546955  0.95515939 0.47123327 0.93544655 0.52027235
0.23231433 0.45185196 0.78456432 0.92415415 0.22408711 0.82322069
0.12670252 0.50150037 0.2546955  0.93881636 0.33043862 0.52027235
0.07964735 0.11961717 0.79551265 0.0378607  0.34080482 0.87411928
0.85397911 0.9874083  0.18885285 0.93140091 0.87411928 0.52027235
0.48716601 0.19411124 0.06473023 0.79551265 0.76781874 0.81180605
0.06833817 0.45406719 0.54006639 0.48002784 0.12468554 0.38630289
0.18068918 0.9874083  0.79551265 0.43924601 0.86979492 0.15120609
0.56046085 0.27958234 0.50261158 0.23231433 0.42496329 0.98404103
0.93881636 0.96244002 0.38049589 0.9874083  0.38354959 0.8624937
0.48716601 0.89951127 0.98404103 0.37245044 0.38630289 0.49835809
0.9874083  0.27773467 0.98404103 0.40968608 0.3587635  0.1003149
0.2572435  0.52492011 0.19933781 0.38538261 0.24401876 0.06473023
0.82322069]

**y_test** [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 01]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/deepface/tests/Ensemble-Face-Recognition.py", line 897, in <module>
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_proba)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py", line 776, in roc_curve
    y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py", line 539, in _binary_clf_curve
    raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: unknown format is not supported
```

Comment: Are you using the same `sklearn` version after updating python ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not remember whether i am using same version or different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if we print the value of `type_of_target(y_test)` the output value is "unknown". Now, we have to change the unknown to integer. So we will do like this

```
y_test = y_test.astype(int)
```

**Overall Code**

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, roc_auc_score, roc_curve

y_pred_proba = predictions[::, 1]
y_test = y_test.astype(int)


fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_proba)
auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
```